# How to draw an Event-sourcing Decider with mermaid.js?

Tags: event-sourcing, mermaid

I'm trying to draw an event-sourcing decider with mermaid.js from something I've seen in a YT video: https://youtu.be/kgYGMVDHQHs?t=1572.

[image: A decider]

My attempt so far:

```
graph LR
    Command(Command) --> Decide[[Decide]]
    Decide --> Events(NewEvents)
    Events --> Evolve[[Evolve]]
    PreviousState(Previous State) --> Evolve[[Evolve]]
    Evolve --> State(New or Initial State)
    State --> PreviousState
    State --> Decide
```

[Also available on mermaid.live](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNp9kcFOwzAMhl8l8mmVuqlpx9rlwIXtgAQIsRvrDlFjWESbVGk6GNPenSxppcGBXOzf_vJbiU9QaYHA4N3wdk8eXkpF3LnTTcOVmAwxItPpLVlhJQVutyHudgENygPrAyrbTZ7wM2RRIIIYCF0fnEWIo8WzwYPUfbex3OJkVMTL6J97QXkgXHWTiTbkXkkreT0YBNbnHv017W8zvKZUlzrE0KBpuBTuf06XSgl2jw2WwFwquPkooVRnx_He6s1RVcCs6TGGvhXOcSW5-9ZmLLZcvWp9LYGd4AsYXcyWlN7kS5qlSZEkeRHDEViaJLMsX8yzeZYuaE6L4hzDt3egMaCQVpvHsD2_xHHs2neAvfG6w_MP6S-Zgg)

Which gives something like below:

[image]

It looks really clunky, I'm wondering how the different elements can be better positioned to look more like the first picture?

Answer (score 1):

The video mentioned loop several times, perhaps the plot can be designed like this?

[image]

Try this sample code in [Mermaid Live Editor](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNpNUMtuAjEM_JXIZ_iBPVSqCgektodybHpwN6ZESuxV1tmqYvl3shhR7IOt8Xj8OEEvgaCDn4LD0b1-eHbNXiRn5ODW6ye3oT4GMtxtJ0kTXfHtRKyerTDWb1N4_kwiw5ehIRbqNQrfhR_653f6dVLcjqNGTG6vqDQ_TrP8n0zLxHE2DaMQh9sKSzCHFWQqGWNod52Wogc9UiYPXUsDHbAm9eD53KhYVfZ_3EOnpdIK6hDaHpuI7Z4M3QHT2FAKUaW82a-uLztfADe-Zzk):

```
graph LR
    Command --> Decide
    Evolve --> Event

    subgraph A[loop]
    direction LR
    Evolve --> |New or Initial State|Decide
    Decide --> |New events|Evolve
    end
```

Comment: Hey, that's a very interesting take, need to ponder a bit